# How to convert Response.Redirect path to strongly typed folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET WebForms application, I use a lot of redirects that I format as follows:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Shared/Pages/ManageQuote/InternalReview.aspx")
```

Is it possible to convert the path to strongly typed folder, something like this:

```
Reponse.Redirect(FolderHelper.Root.Shared.Pages.ManageQuote.InternalReview)
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use constants in a static class.

Comment: That was my first idea but decided to ask if someone has done it differently

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: So I can get rid of magic strings and use IntelliSense.